# Assigning values to a new column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame with the following sample data:

[image]

I need to a new column (I've used add_column) "CAGE_LOCATION".
The new values need to be based on conditions/rules for the Bldg and Bldg-Room as follows:

- Bldg 5A   = 1
- Bldg 62   = 2
- Bldg 62-A = 4
- Bldg ARL  = 5
- Bldg-Room 53C-106 = 6
- Bldg-Room 5A-147 = 7
- Bldg-Room 5A-157 = 7

All other Bldg = 3.

Desired outcome should be as below:

[image]

I have tried a merge using a Location dataframe and also ifelse statements. But only part of the list gets correct value.

output from dput:

```
structure(list(Bldg = c("Bldg 53A", "Bldg 53A", "Bldg 53A", "Bldg 53A", 
"Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", 
"Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", 
"Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", "Bldg 53C", 
"Bldg 53C", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", 
"Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", 
"Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 5A", "Bldg 62", "Bldg 62-A", 
"Bldg 62-A", "Bldg 62-A", "Bldg 62-A", "Bldg 62-A", "Bldg 62-A"
), `Bldg-Room` = c("53A-113", NA, "53A-114", NA, "53C-102", NA, 
"53C-104", "53C-109", NA, NA, "53C-110 MS", NA, NA, NA, "53C-121", 
NA, "53C-122", NA, "53C-123", NA, "53C-131", NA, NA, "5A-142", 
NA, NA, NA, "5A-143", NA, NA, NA, "5A-146", "5A-148", NA, NA, 
"5A-157", "5A-181", "5A-183", "62-110", "62A-176", NA, "62A-178", 
NA, "62A-179 MS", NA), CAGE_LOCATION_TYPE = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-45L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is based in the tidyverse and uses the general vectorised if statement `case_when()`. It creates `CAGE_LOCATION` by juxtaposing and prioritizing the variables `X` and `Y` that came from the use of `case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(X = case_when(Bldg == 'Bldg 5A' ~ 1,
                       Bldg == 'Bldg 62' ~ 2,
                       Bldg == 'Bldg 62-A' ~ 4,
                       Bldg == 'Bldg ARL' ~ 5,
                       TRUE ~ 3),
         Y = case_when(`Bldg-Room` == '53C-106' ~ 6,
                       `Bldg-Room` == '5A-147' ~ 7,
                       `Bldg-Room` == '5A-157' ~ 7,
                       TRUE ~ NA_real_),
         CAGE_LOCATION = if_else(is.na(Y), X, Y)) %>%
  select(-X, -Y)

#         Bldg  Bldg-Room CAGE_LOCATION_TYPE CAGE_LOCATION
# 1   Bldg 53A    53A-113                  3             3
# 2   Bldg 53A       <NA>                  3             3
# 3   Bldg 53A    53A-114                  3             3
# 4   Bldg 53A       <NA>                  3             3
# 5   Bldg 53C    53C-102                  3             3
# 6   Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 7   Bldg 53C    53C-104                  3             3
# 8   Bldg 53C    53C-109                  3             3
# 9   Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 10  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 11  Bldg 53C 53C-110 MS                  3             3
# 12  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 13  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 14  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 15  Bldg 53C    53C-121                  3             3
# 16  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 17  Bldg 53C    53C-122                  3             3
# 18  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 19  Bldg 53C    53C-123                  3             3
# 20  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 21  Bldg 53C    53C-131                  3             3
# 22  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 23  Bldg 53C       <NA>                  3             3
# 24   Bldg 5A     5A-142                  1             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a lookup table and then join it to each of the two match columns of your data. Then you can replace any missing values with 3.

First, let's create a reproducible dataframe in the same format as your data. I use "OTHER LOCATION" to make it obvious where we don't expect a match in a given column.

```
library(conflicted)
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <-
  tibble(
    Bldg = c(
      "Bldg 5A",
      "Bldg 5A",
      "Bldg 5A",
      "Bldg ARL",
      "OTHER LOCATION",
      "OTHER LOCATION"
    ),
    Bldg_Room = c(
      "OTHER_LOCATION",
      "OTHER_LOCATION",
      "OTHER_LOCATION",
      "OTHER_LOCATION",
      "Bldg-Room 53C-106",
      "OTHER LOCATION"
    )
  )
```

Now create the lookup table.

```
building_lookup <-
  tibble(
    key = c(
      "Bldg 5A",
      "Bldg 62",
      "Bldg 62-A",
      "Bldg ARL",
      "Bldg-Room 53C-106",
      "Bldg-Room 5A-147",
      "Bldg-Room 5A-157"
    ),
    value = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7)
  )
```

Finally, join your data to the lookup table twice (once for each match column) and replace any missing values of `CAGE_LOCATION` with 3 using `replace_na()`.

```
sample_data %>%
  left_join(building_lookup, by = c("Bldg" = "key")) %>%
  left_join(building_lookup, by = c("Bldg_Room" = "key")) %>% 
  mutate(CAGE_LOCATION = ifelse(is.na(value.x), value.y, value.x)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("value")) %>% 
  mutate(CAGE_LOCATION = replace_na(CAGE_LOCATION, 3))
```

Comment: I like this direction, but it would be great to have header with packages that are required for your solution to work

Comment: @Bulat I noticed a few problems as soon as I hit save. Editing now.

Comment: @Bulat I just edited my answer to add the `library()` calls and to make the lookup work across both of the match columns.